# format Date in code behind or in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime-format

I am developing a website. i am taking date as input from user and depending upon date entered i filter the results from DB. Problem i am facing is that format of date in code behind(i.e 1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM) is different from format of column in sql server (i.e. 2016-10-08 17:58:12.000). first difference is in sql time is in 24 hour format 2ndly in c# year/month/date are being separated using "/" while in sql year-month-date are being separated by "-" thats why it doesnot compare correctly. i want same format of dates on both side. can anyone help. Thanks

**EDIT**

```
protected void searchRecords(DateTime startDate, DateTime finishDate, DateTime startTime, DateTime finishTime, String receiver) {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_GetRecords", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter sDate = new SqlParameter("@sDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sDate.Value = startDate;
            sDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            command.Parameters.Add(sDate);
            SqlParameter fDate = new SqlParameter("@fDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            fDate.Value = finishDate;
            fDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            command.Parameters.Add(fDate);
            SqlParameter sTime = new SqlParameter("@sTime", SqlDbType.DateTime );
            sTime.Value = startTime;
            sTime.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            command.Parameters.Add(sTime);
            SqlParameter fTime = new SqlParameter("@fTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            fTime.Value = finishTime;
            fTime.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            command.Parameters.Add(fTime);
            SqlParameter rcvr = new SqlParameter("@rcvr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            rcvr.Value = receiver;
            rcvr.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            command.Parameters.Add(rcvr);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            try
            {
                connection.Open();

               // String resultMessage = command.Parameters["@sDate"].Value.ToString();

                reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lblreport.Text = reader["username"].ToString();
                }

            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                lblreport.Text = e.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();

            }

        }
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetRecords]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @sDate dateTime,
    @fDate dateTime,
    @sTime dateTime,
    @fTime dateTime,
    @rcvr nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @startDate datetime;
set @startDate = CONVERT(datetime,@sDate);
set @sql ='select * from outbox where 1=1  ';
    if(@sDate is not null)
        set @sql = @sql + 'and acceptedfordeliverytime >= @sDate  '; 
    if(@rcvr is not null)
        set @sql = @sql + ' and receiver=@rcvr';
    Declare @params nvarchar(500)
    SELECT @params ='@sDate DateTime,'+
                    '@fDate DateTime,'+
                    '@sTime DateTime,'+
                    '@fTime DateTime,'+
                    '@rcvr nvarchar(50)'

     exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,@sDate,@fDate,@sTime,@fTime,@rcvr
```

Comment: You don't need the same format unless you use string variables, have you tried to compare using DateTime objects?

Comment: yes dates on both side are of type dateTime

Comment: DateTime in sql server as well as in c# does not store display format. Please edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: Make sure the data type of @StartDate is DateTime, as well as the value you are passing to that parameter in your c# code.

Comment: `SqlParameter sDate = new SqlParameter("sDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);` should be `SqlParameter sDate = new SqlParameter("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);`. What type is the value you are sending to it? should be of type `DateTime`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled check both are of same type. i.e DateTime

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant c# code as well as the stored procedure.

Comment: Check Edited question and for your ease i have changed selected columns and select * for receiver its working but if i search using sdate it doesnot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `acceptedfordeliverytime >= @sDate` returns no records, probably since the time portion of `@sDate` is after the time portion of `acceptedfordeliverytime`.

Try to pass the `@sDate` with midnight as the time portion, like this:

```
SqlParameter sDate = new SqlParameter("@sDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sDate.Value = startDate.Date;
sDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
command.Parameters.Add(sDate);
```

btw, that can be shortened to

```
command.Parameters.Add("@sDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate.Date;
```

and use it in sql like this:

```
if(@sTime is not null)
    set @sql = @sql + 'and acceptedfordeliverytime >= @sDate and acceptedfordeliverytime < dateadd(day, 1, @sDate) ';
```

Comment: you still don't get any results back?

Comment: no. reader is not receiving any data. which might the case that there is no match with date parameters

Comment: ok i tried one thing i commented all the if condition and then tried to get result and it does not show any result. but if i use receiver to get result it shows result.

Comment: Do you get results with `select * from outbox where 1=1` only?

Comment: no even from this i am not getting any result. now the only difference is that textbox for receiver is asp:textbox.

Comment: if there would be no record then how there are results when i search for receiver

Comment: I'm lost. You are getting results from `select * from outbox where 1=1`?

Comment: I have removed where 1=1 and its working now. I have no idea how but its working.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to format dates into a format in C# to send it to SQL Server if you are using `DateTime` type. You should not need to cast on the SQL Server side either if the column is of type `datetime`. However, if you still need to format it for whatever reason, here is how:

```
var readyForSql = someDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) about date formats.

Comment: Wrong. No point of casting dates to strings, since .Net DateTime maps directly to Sql Server's DateTime. passing DateTime as a parameter is the correct way to pass dates from .Net to Sql server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes but I wrote my answer before the OP mentioned they were dates on both sides.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's still wrong to pass strings as datetime values from .net to sql server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled why is it wrong if the stored procedure is written to take a string instead of datetime and you cannot change the stored procedure?

Comment: If you can't change the stored procedure then that's a different story, but if you can control both sides (.net and sql server) then the correct way is to pass .Net datetime to Sql server Datetime directly, without using strings at all. If you have to pass strings, the format should be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff` (Note the `T` separator between the date portion and the time portion.